# dialog code wrong somewere?

Tags: android, dialog

Can someone help with this code. what am looking for is for the button on my dialog to go back a pagewhen the users  press the button.so i dont have to press the phone back button thank you.

java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class DlogActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Dialog dialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main2);
dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
@SuppressWarnings("unused")Button button01 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);


 Intent intent = new Intent(DlogActivity.this, DlogActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();



                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                                                                                                                                                                            public void onBackPressed() {   
      dialog.cancel();
    // Simply Dismiss the dialog to make it close and return to back..
            /*What you are using is not a valid construct */   
            }



        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    }

}
```

xml.code

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Button" />




   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="236dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp" android:background="@drawable/carsee"/>


   <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you mean to say, when user presses a button of dialog box, it should be disapeard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the problem is at below code,

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main2);
```

you cannot give layout like this, instead you need to inflate layout to your dialog.